# appname.exe.config no está en la carpeta de la aplicación

Tags: c#, windows-forms, deployment, app.config

Estoy compilando una aplicación "MiApp" de Visual Studio Community 2017.

Luego genero un Deplyment Project para generar el archivo .MSI

Se supone que el archivo App.Config en el destino de instalación bajo "Archivos de programa" se convertiría en MiApp.exe.config, pero éste archivo no aparece, sin embargo al correr el programa funciona como si allí estuviera.

El App.Config contiene Settings tanto de usuario como se aplicación.

¿Dónde está el archivo .config?

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el motivo.

Estoy usando Dotfuscator, la carpeta de salida de dotfuscator es una diferente a la Bin\Release que genera la compilación. Al Deployment Project le agregaba los ensamblados ofuscados.

La solución fue:

1. Crear normalmente el Deployment Project como si no fuera a ofuscar.
2. Proceder con la ofuscación.
3. Sobre escribir los ensamblados de la carpeta Bin\Release con los ofuscados.
4. Compilar el Deplyment Project.

   Si hay alguna manera mejor de hacerlo, se agradecen los comentarios.